# this code work with N=348 but dont work when N = 349

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, if-statement, infinite-loop

why dose this sorting code work with N=348 but when N=349 program hang.?there is not compilation  error.

```
#define N 348
int main(void){
  int n[N];
  int temp;

  for(int i=0;i<N;i++) n[i] = rand();

  for(int i=0 ; i<N-1;){
    if (n[i]<n[i+1]) {i++;continue;}
    else {
       temp = n[i];
       n[i] = n[i+1];
       n[i+1] = temp;
       if (i != 0) i--;
       else i++;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `i` for both the loops?

Comment: @ParthShah: The loops are separate, not nested, despite the indentation.

Comment: Ah my bad. Thanks @EricPostpischil

Comment: The program does not hang for me. `rand` implementations differ between C implementations, so I modified the program to try different values in place of `N` and multiple runs with different `rand` samples, and it did not hang. Please construct a [mre] that does not use `rand`. (One way to do this is to print the values produced by `rand`, then rewrite the program to have those values in an array initialized with them.)

Comment: Also, please indent the program consistently; the second `for` statement should not be more indented than the first if it is not within the body of the first. And there should have been a `#include <stdlib.h>` to declare `rand`. And, for an [mre], the value of `N` should be set to the failing case, 349, not the working case, 348. Readers should be able to reproduce the problem by copying and pasting the code and executing it with no changes.

Comment: Same, I am able to execute it no problems.

Comment: The problem can't be associated with changing the value of `N` in such a subtle manner. The cause needs to be something else.

Comment: this program runs for me without problems.
reasons that may crash your code are either random number combination or that your stack size is very small therefore when you define 'int n[N];' it fails.

anyway, you need to supply more information like the error message and non-random numbers

Comment: when delete sorting part there is not problem.this mean rand() or stack size has not issue.Tank you for your replay.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  The main problem being that it is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` for the `rand()` function.  Also, before calling `rand()` should have: `#include <time.h>` and `srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );`

Comment: I ran the OPs code with both values and it did not fail.

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of the program does not depend on the value of `N`.

In case when two consecutive elements of the array are equal each other there will be infinite loop due to this condition

```
if (n[i]<n[i+1]) {i++;continue;}
else {
```

and this statement inside the compound else statement

```
if (i != 0) i--;
```

That is the else statement will be always executed when `n[i]` is equal to `n[i+1]`.

For example try to run the program for the array

```
#define N 3
//...
int n[N] = { 1, 2, 2 };
```

You can avoid the error by changing the condition to

```
if (n[i]<=n[i+1]) {i++;continue;}
else {
```

Comment: Well spotted! You should emphasize that the problem is mainly caused by `if (i != 0) i--;`.

Comment: out of the problem `if (n[i]<=n[i+1]) {i++;continue;}` on one line also with a useless *continue* is not very clear